# JFreeChart's barChart

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfreechart, jtabbedpane

I have created a dataset (of type `DefaultCategoryDataSet`) for creating a bar chart (say barChart) with the `JFreeChart` api: `ChartFactory.createBarChart(...)`. Then I created a `ChartPanel` - CP, and added the barChart to it. Finally I added the CP to the `JPanel`. This `JPanel` is binded to a `JTabbedPane`'s tab for showing the panel containing my bar chart. Everything runs fine except that the bar chart is not fully fitting into the available panel space. Some parts of the bar chart (left and right) are being cut and not shown. Is there any way of accomodating the entire bar chart. Please note that it's not the data due to which it is not shown entirely (even with fewer data, the problem persists). Also, I am able to display a pie-chart in my tab without any issues.

Comment: ok. setting the preferred size (dimension.width) of the chart panel did the trick for me.

Comment: You can also override the `ChartPanel` method `getPreferredSize()`. You are allowed to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).